# What is fat db in parity

Tags: parity

What does `fat_db` option in parity do? I don't understand its description from [docs](https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity-Ethereum.html):

```
Build appropriate information to allow enumeration of all accounts and 
storage keys. Doubles the size of the state database.
```

What kind of information is meant here?
Which RPC requests become available if I run fatdb?

Is "Doubles the size of database" just an estimation or is it always two times bigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some rpc calls in `parity` module would be available:

https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module